# Render layers with and without HDR background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

I have a scene with a house in front of the camera and behind the house some trees. I want to render them in separate layers, but I want the HDR image in the background for the first render and without in the second render with only the trees.

I can only check the Transparent in the Film section in the Render tab, but that affect both render layers. I guess I can render them manually one by one and change the settings for Transparent, but perhaps there are some other alternative?

EDIT:
I'm not asking HOW to render a background with HDR image! I have two render layers. The first render layer I want to render with the HDR background and in the second render layer without the HDR background. But if I enable the Transparent option, both render layer are affected by this settings and the HDR background isn't visible in any render layer. How to fix this was my question.

Comment: I'm not asking HOW to render a background with HDR image! I have two render layers. The first render layer I want to render with the HDR background and in the second render layer without the HDR background. But if I enable the Transparent option, both render layer are affected by this settings and the HDR background isn't visible in any render layer. How to fix this was my question.

Comment: You enable the environment pass and combine them in the compositor.